# Cocos2d-x V3.0 scrollview usage

Tags: ios, scrollview, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, ccscrollview

How to include and use ScrollView in Cocos2d-x project?

By simply writing

```
 #include "CCScrollView.h"
```

is not helping & generates compilation issues for both iOS & Android? (Haven't checked for other platforms)

Can someone help me how to `include` it?

File location is in `MyProject/cocos2d/extensions/GUI/CCScrollView`

**Edit:**
Cocos2d version : Cocos2d-x V3
Should work for : atleast iOS, Android
Current OS : mac os x

**Errors I get** :

Android:
[image]

iOS:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add ScrollView to the cocos2d-x 3.x project you have to write next import in the top of your class implementation file:

```
#include "extensions/cocos-ext.h"
USING_NS_CC_EXT;
```

After that you will be able to create scroll view with following syntax:

```
auto scrollView = ScrollView::create();
```

Also, while compiling native code for Android, make sure you uncomment next two lines in Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_extension_static
```

and

```
$(call import-module,extensions)
```